# How to get the list specific multiple links in Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I need to get list of links from a webpage it has href="/example/*" it doesn't have any specific class name or id.

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

Right now, I'm getting all the links in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do the filter in the xpath itself (recommended approach)

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/example/')]")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

or you can fetch and then filter

```py
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    href = elem.get_attribute("href")
    if '/example/' in href:
       print(href)
```

Comment: how about if i wanted to locate it also in specific div? for an example 
<div class="content">
...
#list is here
...
</div>

Comment: Then you would use `//div[@class='content']//a[contains(@href, '/example/')]'`